# Sum of values with added percentage keeps giving wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, decimal, numeric

Ik keep getting wrong amounts when I want to sum prices and then add VAT to it. 
I have the following situation:

Let's say I have 4 products and I want them show them on a invoice. Each products has the same price of 2.50.

I have the following code:

```
@products = Product.find([1,2,3,4])
```

On the invoice I have:

```
@products.each do |product|

  %p
    Price without VAT:
    = number_to_currency(product.price) --> Gives € 2,50

  %p
    Price with 21% VAT: 
    = number_to_currency(product.price / 100 * 121) --> Gives € 3,03
```

This shows like this:

- Price without VAT:  € 2,50
- Price with 21% VAT: € 3,03

Now I want to add a total line. I have tried something like this:

```
 - sum = @products.sum( &:price ) --> Gives 10
%p
  Total with 21% VAT: 
  = number_to_currency(sum / 100 * 121 ) --> Gives € 12,10 instead of € 12,12
```

What I try, I keep getting a total price including VAT on € 12.10 instead of € 12,12. (4 x € 3,03 = € 12,12)

I have the price in my database as:

```
t.decimal "price"
```

The price is stored as 2.5

Who can help me out with this?

Comment: Your math is wrong.. it should be `((product.price * 121) /  100)`. No?

Comment: No, to add VAT it should be: price / 100 * 121. (2.50 / 100) * 121 = 3,025 -> € 3,03

Comment: I read it like it costs 121 with VAT when the actual price is 100, Am I right?

Comment: Costs is 2.50 without VAT. With 21% VAT it's 3.03

Comment: forget your numbers for now. Say you have 100, and adding 21% VAT to it, what will be the number now?

Comment: If I use 100 as a unit price, I get a total price of € 484 because there are no decimals to round up.

Comment: I was expecting simple 121 with 21% VAT when the actual price is 100. I don't know from where you got 363. Anyway good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One product's correct VAT amount:

```
(BigDecimal.new("2.5") / 100 * 121).to_f #=> 3.025
```

4 products correct VAT amount:

```
(BigDecimal.new("10") / 100 * 121).to_f #=> 12.10
```

Options:

1. don't round up and then you can calculate the total VAT from total sum
2. Round up, but then calculate total VAT as sum of VAT amounts per product

Applying what's said above, 1 product with VAT:

```
(product.price / 100 * 121).round(2)
```

all products with VAT:

```
products.sum { |p| (p.price / 100 * 121).round(2) }
```

Comment: Why are you converting it to `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit his datatype ***is*** decimal, so I'm just reproducing

Comment: But on a invoice you must use the round up prices. So one product will be € 3,03, and If  I use your code I get for 4 products again € 12,10 instead of 4 x 3,03

Comment: You don't need `BigDecimal` for that.. Just do `10 / 100.0 * 121` it will floating point math.

Comment: @Jerry, you either don't round or you do and adjust your math. I edited the answer. there's no third option

Comment: No that's not working. I still get € 12,10 instead of € 12,12

Comment: @Jerry you gotta be kidding me, right? What's not working? You have to take a moment and realize, that it's not the numbers are incorrect, but your POV. The math is dead simple here. Just think about it and don't post nonsense like "it's still not working". Just FYI: `number_to_currency` does the rounding, so your take here is to sum VATs per product

Comment: 3.025 will become € 3,03 and (4 x 3.025) will become € 12,10 in your code. And that is not good. On an invoice it should be ( 4 x € 3,03) = € 12,12

Comment: @Jerry I deeply hope that over time you will come back to this question and laugh at what you say now. Anyway, 1 product with VAT: `(product.price / 100 * 121).round(2)`, 4 products with VAT: `products.sum { |p| (p.price / 100 * 121).round(2) }`